# Assign variable for fixed path to FSO to scan folder and subfolders

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an excel macro, which loops through the different subfolders of a fixed parent folder. The parent folder directory does not change. I have found a code on the net, which first lets me choose the folder to scan, which is nice, but is awkward for my purpose, since I run the code several times and each time I have to choose the folder again.
Instead I would like to give the macro the fixed full path and do without the prompt to choose the folder. I have written the following code, but do not know how to adjust it to make it work the way I described. Could you give me some advise?

This is the code:

```
Dim MyPath As String, MyFolderName As String, MyFileName As String, strStartCell2 As String, strFolderToScan As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim F As Boolean
Dim objShell As Object, objFolder As Object, AllFolders As Object, AllFiles As Object, strFileFormat As Object, fso As Object
Dim MySheet As Worksheet

'Define variables and constants
Set strFileFormat = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Makro").Range("A6")
strStartCell2 = strStartCell
strFolderToScan = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Makro").Range("C4").Value & "\"

'Select folder
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please select the folder you would like to scan", 0, 0)
If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
    MyPath = objFolder.self.Path & "\"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = MyPath
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
 
'List all folders
Set AllFolders = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set AllFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
AllFolders.Add (MyPath), ""
i = 0
Do While i < AllFolders.Count
    Key = AllFolders.keys
    MyFolderName = Dir(Key(i), vbDirectory)
    Do While MyFolderName <> ""
        If MyFolderName <> "." And MyFolderName <> ".." Then
            If (GetAttr(Key(i) & MyFolderName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                AllFolders.Add (Key(i) & MyFolderName & "\"), ""
            End If
        End If
        MyFolderName = Dir
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
 
'List all files
For Each Key In AllFolders.keys
    MyFileName = Dir(Key & "*." & strFileFormat)
    Do While MyFileName <> ""
        AllFiles.Add (Key & MyFileName), ""
        MyFileName = Dir
    Loop
Next
 
'List all files in Files sheet
Sheets("Makro").Range(strStartCell2).Resize(AllFiles.Count, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(AllFiles.keys)
Set AllFolders = Nothing
Set AllFiles = Nothing
```

Probably this is simple, but i just can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks a lot in advance!
Oliver

Comment: I don't get your issue. You can just use any variable (or constant) and set the path there like: `Dim FixedPath As String: FixedPath = "C:\My\Path\to\Somewhere\"` or a constant like `Const FixedPath As String = "C:\My\Path\to\Somewhere\"`. If that does not solve please improve your question and explain where exactly your issue is.

Comment: Hello PEH, thanks for your quick answer. The fixed path is not the problem, this I already have in the variable strFolderToScan. My question is how do I get this fixed path into the code, so that the program does not ask me to choose a folder, but takes the pre-defined path instead.

Comment: You simple comment all code lines starting from `'select folder` up to `Set objShell = Nothing` and replace with `MyPath = Thisworkbook.path  & "\" & "MyFolder\"`, Followed by `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = MyPath`. Of course, you may use any (valid) path...

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant part for selecting the folder

```
'Select folder
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please select the folder you would like to scan", 0, 0)
If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
    MyPath = objFolder.self.Path & "\"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = MyPath
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Especially the `objShell.BrowseForFolder` is the part that asks you to browse for the folder. So you need to replace that to use `strFolderToScan` directly. We do that by using `objShell.GetFolder(strFolderToScan)` to get the folder from your path `strFolderToScan`.

But I recommend to check if the folder actually exists, so you do not run into errors:

```
'Select folder
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
If objShell.FolderExists(strFolderToScan) Then
    MyPath = strFolderToScan
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = MyPath
Else
    MsgBox "The folder '" & strFolderToScan & "' does not exist."
    Exit Sub
End If
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Hello PEH, thanks for contribution. The idea given by FaneDuru was however easier to understand for me. I nevertheless tried your code also, but wasn't successful in implementing it into my code to make it work. However, many thanks also to you!

Comment: It's just replacing the first code block in my answer with the second code block. That's it.